# How to use actions on Formik forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, formik

I want to reset my Formik form every time the form is submitted. Instead of `submitForm(email);`I am trying `submitForm(actions, email)` so that I am able to call

```
actions.resetForm()
```

inside `submitForm()` but I get`Cannot find name 'actions'.ts(2304)`

```
 let submitForm = (email: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
      variables: {
        email: email,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<DeleteUserResponse>) => {
          setIsRemoved(true);
      })
      .catch((error: { message: string }) => {
        setIsRemoved(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}>
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched,
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: FormEvent) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
          };
          return (
            <div className="main-content">
              <form
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(email);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <CustomButton
                    disabled={!isValid || !email}
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
```

Or if there's an easier way to reset text-fields, that would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
onSubmit={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitForm(email);
    }}>
```

to

```
  onSubmit={e => {
        e.stopPropagation()
          handleSubmit(e)
        }}>
```

add handleSubmit event in

```
const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched,
             handleSubmit        <-- this
          } = props;
```

in onSubmit

```
onSubmit={(values, actions) =>
```

Add function

```
submitForm(values.email);
```

note : onsubmit is a property of `<Formik onSubmit={...` 
you can get all values on this function
do not get from `<form onSubmit`

Comment: Could you please add how I could write a handleChange? I couldn't get the syntax right in Typescript. Also, I am already using ```onSubmit={(values, actions) =>```. Should I pass ```submitForm(values.email);```after the timeout? I am afraid it will disturb the program logic

Comment: Or if there's an easier way to reset text-fields, that would be nice too.

Comment: @a125 try use  <Field or  use onChange={handleChange} pass it from const {handleChange, ... = props

Comment: don't use onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')} 
remove it